# Uninstalling Python

Tags: software-installation, python, uninstall, python3, pip

I have two versions of python3 (3.5 and 3.8) on the same machine(ubuntu 16.04). And I guess the installation is broken. I want to uninstall them completely and install afresh. Can someone tell me the safest way of doing this without messing up dependencies ?

EDIT:
tarball-extract-config that's how i installed v3.8

Comment: How you safely uninstall something depends entirely upon how you originally installed it. Apt? Tarball? Something else?

Comment: tarball-extract-config that's how i installed v3.8

Answer (score 2):

> I want to uninstall them completely and install afresh. Can someone tell me the safest way of doing this without messing up dependencies?

This exact goal won't be possible, uninstalling a package will uninstall all the packages which depend on it. Additionally the `python3` package that came with Ubuntu 16.04 is likely depended upon by many vital system packages like `gnome-shell` for instance.

I would recommend finding the package from which `python3.8` came and uninstalling just that package. You can find the package which provides it with the following command:

```
dpkg -S $(which python3.8)
```

Which should print out something like:

```
package-name: /usr/bin/python3.8
```

You can take the actual name (as represented by `package-name`) and find what depends upon that you have installed with this command (again replacing `package-name` with the name you got from the above command:

```
apt-cache rdepends --installed package-name
```

Save this list somewhere and review it to make sure you're ok with uninstalling these packages. If you are happy with uninstalling those packages you can do so with:

```
sudo apt-get purge package-name
```

This will uninstall the package and all the related configuration files. You might want to then try reinstalling the standard `python3` package to regenerate any configuration files that might have gotten overwritten by the package which provided `python3.8` and were subsequently removed. You can do that with:

```
sudo apt-get reinstall python3
```

Then you should be back to (relatively) clean python state. Again I would make sure you're comfortable removing everything which depends on Python 3.8 but on Ubuntu 16.04 that shouldn't be any vital system software.

Comment: first command produces this     dpkg -S $(which python3.8)
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/local/bin/python3.8

Comment: Looks like the OP installed from a tarball, so apt-based methods of removal won't work. Too bad, because this is a really well-written answer!

Comment: yeah so well written that I wanna go back in time and do this the other way :v

Comment: @JashwanthSai if you installed via tarball what does `which python3.8` show you?

Comment: hi! I tried creating a dpkg package using checkinstall and then installed and removed it but it still wont go.

Comment: Also somehow the symbolic link got broken or something and now my gnome-terminal won't open.